# Play next audio file in listview

Tags: android, listview

I am using media player to play audio files from raw folder with a listview.
Everything work good but i have a problem.
The problem is:
When first audio file ends, it play the second file but when second file ends it doesn't play the third file.
What is the problem??
I try to add setOnCompletionListener on mp and reset mp and play audion in (position+1)
Is it true??

And i have another question.
When it end playing the first item in listview and start playing second item , the first item background still colored (blue) and it isn't colored the second item background.
Can somebody help me pleaaassseee

This is my code

```
private final String[] listContent = { "song1", "song2","song3"};

private final int[] resID = { R.raw.song1, R.raw.song2, R.raw.song3 };


    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mainList = (ListView)     findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =   new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                                             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContent);
                                                            mainList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mainList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void    onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                                    final int position,final long id) {
                playSong(position);

                String selectedSweet =     mainList.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                tv1.setText(selectedSweet);
                   System.out.println(selectedSweet);

                   mainList.setSelector(R.drawable.selecteditem);
                   btnn2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);        



                   mp.setOnCompletionListener(new    OnCompletionListener(){

                                @Override public void   onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){  

            String selectedSweet2 =    mainList.getItemAtPosition(position+1).toString();
            tv1.setText(selectedSweet2);

//There to play next file
               mainlist.setSelection(position+1);
              mainList.setSelector(R.drawable.selecteditem);

                                playSong2(position);


                                }
});}
                        private void playSong2(int    songIndex)
                                {

                                    mp.reset();
    mp =    MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), resID[songIndex]);

                                    mp.start();


                                }});






    }




public void playSong(int songIndex) {

    mp.reset();
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), resID[songIndex]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of both of your question is that the end of song will not cause any change in the index of listview. try to update the listview index upon the end of song.

Comment: Ok.  but how to update the listview index upon the end of song??

Answer (score 0):

At first, what is the position value at "playSong(position)"?

And to what position value does it go?

Comment: It go to the position of selected item of the listview,

Comment: you checked that using debugger? Cause it starts with 0, not with 1

Comment: each time you call "position", set underneath it : **Log.wtf("position : ", String.valueOf(position));** and then show us  the log file